# problem with .net windows service

Tags: windows, vb.net, service

have written a windows service. while the code worked for a simple form app, its not working in a windows service. here;s the code

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Service1

Public Shared Function CheckProxy(ByVal Proxy As String) As Boolean
    Dim myWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://google.com"),    HttpWebRequest)
    myWebRequest.Proxy = New WebProxy(Proxy, False)
    myWebRequest.Timeout = 10000
    Try
        Dim myWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim loResponseStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Return True
    Catch ex As WebException
        If (ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure) Then

        End If
        Return False
    End Try
End Function


Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\AuthorLog.txt",
        "AuthorLogService has been started at " & Now.ToString())
    MsgBox("1")
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    MsgBox("2")
    ' Check if the the Event Log Exists 
    If Not Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Evoain Proxy Bot") Then
        Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyService", "Myservice Log") ' Create Log 
    End If
    ' Write to the Log 
    Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService Log", "This is log on " & _
    CStr(TimeOfDay), EventLogEntryType.Information)

    Dim ProxyURLList As New Chilkat.CkString
    Dim ProxyListPath As New Chilkat.CkString
    Dim WorkingProxiesFileData As New Chilkat.CkString
    Dim ProxyArray(10000000) As String
    Dim event1 As New Chilkat.CkString
    event1.setString("started")
    event1.saveToFile("B:\serv.txt", "utf-8")
    Dim ns As Integer = 0
    'Read Configuration File
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim srFileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim sInputLine As String
    sFileName = "config.ini"
    srFileReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(sFileName)
    sInputLine = srFileReader.ReadLine()
    Dim temp As New Chilkat.CkString
    Do Until sInputLine Is Nothing
        temp.setString(sInputLine)
        If temp.containsSubstring("proxyurllist=") = True Then
            'Read Proxy-URL-List
            ProxyURLList.setString(sInputLine)
            If ProxyURLList.containsSubstring("proxyurllist=") = True Then
                ProxyURLList.replaceFirstOccurance("proxyurllist=", "")
            End If
        ElseIf temp.containsSubstring("finalproxylistpath=") = True Then
            'Read Proxy-List-Path
            ProxyListPath.setString(sInputLine)
            If ProxyListPath.containsSubstring("finalproxylistpath=") = True Then
                ProxyListPath.replaceFirstOccurance("finalproxylistpath=", "")

            End If
        End If
        sInputLine = srFileReader.ReadLine()
    Loop
    '*********Scrape URLs From Proxy-URL-List*********************
    Dim ProxyURLFileData As New Chilkat.CkString
    ProxyURLFileData.loadFile(ProxyURLList.getString, "utf-8")


    Dim MultiLineString As String = ProxyURLFileData.getString

    Dim ProxyURLArray() As String = MultiLineString.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ProxyURLArray.Count - 1

        '********Scrape Proxies From Proxy URLs***********************
        Dim http As New Chilkat.Http()
        Dim success As Boolean
        ' Any string unlocks the component for the 1st 30-days.
        success = http.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial")
        If (success <> True) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Send the HTTP GET and return the content in a string.
        Dim html As String
        html = http.QuickGetStr(ProxyURLArray(i))
        Dim links As MatchCollection
        links = Regex.Matches(html, "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,5}")
        For Each match As Match In links
            Dim matchUrl As String = match.Groups(0).Value
            ProxyArray(ns) = matchUrl
            ns = ns + 1
        Next
    Next
    '*************CHECK URLs*****************
    Dim cnt As Integer = 0
    For cnt = 0 To 1

        Dim ProxyStatus As Boolean = CheckProxy("http://" + ProxyArray(cnt) + "/")

        If ProxyStatus = True Then
            WorkingProxiesFileData.append(Environment.NewLine)
            WorkingProxiesFileData.append(ProxyArray(cnt))
        End If
    Next
    WorkingProxiesFileData.saveToFile(ProxyListPath.getString, "utf-8")
End Sub
End Class
```

what are the basic thing i cannot do in a windows service? oh, and i am using the chilkat library too..
why can't i use all of my code in OnStart? i did so and the services stops just as it starts.
can i use something else except a timer and put an endless loop?

Comment: In what way is this not working?

Comment: nothing is happening. it is supposed to be writing to files, popping up msgboxes, but nothings happening.

Comment: Take a look at Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Event Viewer, Windows Logs, Application.  This should show any major faults with the service.  I may be wrong, but I think that using any kind of GUI in service is a bad idea without taking special steps to allow it.  What steps to you take to install and start the service?

Comment: i am trying to run the loop with a timer. not working. i tried creating a new thread does not work.

Comment: caN someone give me a barebone structure of a windows service project?

Comment: As written, this code won't work because of the call to MsgBox in the OnStart function.  Remember, there isn't anybody to push OK!  Does the line get written to AuthorLog.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Running as a windows service typically won't let you see any popup boxes, etc since there's no UI (Unless you check the box to allow interaction with the desktop).

Try adding a Timer1.Start in your OnStart method. Then in your Timer1_Tick method, first thing stop the timer, then at the end start it back up, this way your Tick method won't fire while you're already doing work.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm (very) late to this party, but what kind of timer are you using?  A `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is designed for use in a single threaded Windows Form and will not work in a Windows Service app.  Try a `System.Timers.Timer` instead.